# Passing jQuery thruh eval

Tags: jquery, eval

ObjectI'm using in my project some lines of codes which allows me to do something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-click="test">Run test function</a>
```

And on click it will run `test()`

```
$("body").delegate( "a[data-click]", "click", function(){
    var f = $(this).attr("data-click");

    eval(f + "();");
});
```

My problem now is, that one function needs information (the jQuery Event, particular `.currentTarget`) about the clicked element.
I tried with:

```
$("body").delegate( "a[data-click]", "click", function(event){
    var f = $(this).attr("data-click");
    eval(f + "(" + JSON.stringify(event) + ");");
});
```

But that don't works, because `event` is a cycling object. (And I don't know a way to serialize the jQuery object so that I ca unserialize it and I can call the jQuery functions on it)

So how can I pass the jQuery EventObject?

Comment: Using eval is pretty much always wrong... Why would you ever want to dump code inside an attribute string?!

Comment: Step 1: Don't use `eval()`. With what you're doing, you might as well be using inline event handlers: `onclick="test()"`.

Comment: Create an object and call it's methods using bracket notation.

Comment: Please don't tell me that this is a strange way to call functions, I know-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for eval:

```
$("body").delegate("a[data-click]", "click", function(event) {
    var f = window[$(this).data("click")];
    f();
});
```

Note that this only works when your function is in the global scope (or available through another object which you could specify instead of `window`, the global object).

Also note that you should use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `delegate`:

```
$("body").delegate("a[data-click]", "click", function(event) { // old
$("body").on("click", "a[data-click]", function(event) {       // new
```

Comment: I'm using delegate because it triggers also on elements which are dynamically added after bind.

Comment: [Please read the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `on` works exactly the same way with the parameters I used in my example.

Comment: Oh yes. I was mixing up something.